# Optim of function in R (L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn')

Tags: r

When I run the code below, sometimes there are no problems and sometimes I get the error:

```
Error in stats::optim(x = c(16.0647119767221, 14.2739364736729, 37.6134235608159,  : L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

I understand that this means somewhere I am producing a value that is larger than `.Machine$double.xmax` (`1.797693e+308` on my machine), but I can't figure out which parameter I have to limit to prevent this. Any suggestions?

```
library(MASS)
K <- c(109.106,121,10,38,61,13,45,40,12,33,9,18,44,24,23,7,85)
weib  <-  fitdistr(K,densfun=dweibull,start=list(scale=20,shape=1))

# Bootstrapping the pointwise confidence intervals 
set.seed(123)
rw.small <- rweibull(100,scale=weib$estimate[1], shape=weib$estimate[2])
xs <- seq(0, round(max(K)+25,-1), length=500)
boot.cdf <- sapply(1:1000,function(i){
  xi <- sample(rw.small, size=length(rw.small), replace=TRUE)
  MLE.est <- suppressWarnings(fitdistr(xi, densfun="weibull", lower = 0))  
  pweibull(xs, shape=as.numeric(MLE.est$estimate[1]), scale=as.numeric(MLE.est$estimate[2]))
})
```

Comment: the first two values of K are pretty large. how did you get those

Comment: Perhaps you should specify the start values inside the loop as well.

Comment: K is an observed data set.